# PL\SQL DML instruction

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dml

Is **Commit** a DML instruction in PL\SQL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it's a transaction control (TCL) statement, not a data manipulation (DML) statement.  [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_1001.htm) is a list of SQL statement types.

Answer (score 2):

No COMMIT is not a DML instruction. It comes under TCL. COMMIT is used to save the changes made by using DML instructions. In general COMMIT is used with ROLLBACK.

**DML:**
Data manipulation language (DML) statements access and manipulate data in existing schema objects. These statements do not implicitly commit the current transaction.

CALL

DELETE

EXPLAIN

PLAN

INSERT

LOCK

TABLE

MERGE

SELECT

UPDATE

The SELECT statement is a limited form of DML statement in that it can only access data in the database. It cannot manipulate data in the database, although it can operate on the accessed data before returning the results of the query.
The CALL and EXPLAIN PLAN statements are supported in PL/SQL only when executed dynamically. All other DML statements are fully supported in PL/SQL

**TCL:**
Transaction control statements manage changes made by DML statements

COMMIT

ROLLBACK

SAVEPOINT

SET TRANSACTION